# How to merge two different versions same dataframe in python pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the two different versions of same data frame. In fact, they were two different excels with the same columns updated by two different persons. They may have their own entries as well as the same data. And it looks like this.

```
df1                         df2
A      B       C            A      B     C
prod1  cat1    type1        prod1  cat1  type1  
prod2  cat2                 prod2  cat3  type2
prod3  cat4    type3        prod4  cat5
prod4  cat5    type4
```

What I want to do is that, based on col A, I will merge this two data frames, drop for duplicates, and fill the missing one with the other dataframe has, and if both row has values, will use df2 as priority to take the values. And The final result should look like this.

```
final df
A       B        C
prod1   cat1     type1
prod2   cat3     type2
prod3   cat4     type3
prod4   cat5     type4
```

How can I achieve that in python pandas?

What I have tried is that I changed df2 column names except col A, merged (`left_on='A'`), and add new columns, and fill the values by using `apply` based on df1 columns and df2 columns, but it did not give me the correct answer.

Comment: Don’t describe your code, copy and paste it into the question

Comment: What value is in the empty spaces?

Comment: Also, how do you define duplicates? Is 'A' an index?

Comment: @DYZ Empty spaces will be filled with NaN, and duplicates are based on col A.

Answer (score 0):

You can mutually patch the data frames both ways, stack them, and then eliminate duplicates:

```
pd.concat([df1.fillna(df2), df2.fillna(df1)])\ # Patching and Stacking
  .drop_duplicates(subset=['A']) # Dropping dups
#       A     B      C
#0  prod1  cat1  type1
#1  prod2  cat2  type2
#2  prod3  cat4  type3
#3  prod4  cat5  type4
```